# FirebaseMessasingService gets notifications from my server, but if I use the FirebaseConsole, my class is not being called

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

This is what I have inside my AndroidManifest:

```
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.smooch.core.service.SmoochService" />
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I am using version: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'`

This is how my FirebaseMessagingService looks like:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage message) {
    Log.i("", "MyFirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived");
    final Map data = message.getData();
    FcmService.triggerSmoochNotification(data, this);
    final Map bundle = data;
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("", "GLOBAL intances  before GCM:" + Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(PSApplicationClass.Config));
            try {
                String title = getString(R.string.alert_title_warning) + " " + getString(R.string.trips_remaining_free, user.getTrips_left());
                String message = getString(R.string.alert_freemium_upgrade);
                Notification.generateNotificationStandard(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, title, message, null, null, false, false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Utils.appendLog("GCMIntentService onMessageReceived error: " + e.getMessage(), "E", Constants.PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

And basically I put a breakpoint at the onMessageReceived of this function.

If the server sends a notification to my app, it will be received by this Service, and I can handle it as needed.
BUT. If I use the FirebaseConsole -> GROW -> Could Messaging -> I create a new Message and I send it. My app will get the notifications. but it will be created "automatically" without entering my onMessageReceived method.
How can I force it to do so? 
This is the data that I send via the console:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/7Pp0KJIErZ8XVZZ/upload.png

What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT:

Like I said, I get notifications, but the notifications are being created automatically instead of going through my FirebaseMessaging Service.

I did manage to change the icon like this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
```

But I still need to run other code when I get it, not just show it. and that I do not know how

Comment: Is your app opened when you send the message through the console?

Comment: doesn't matter. Yes or no the same. I do get the notification on my phone. it's just that it doesn't go through my FirebaseMessagingService. it just shows the notification by default.
I did manage to change the icon tho', made an edit

Comment: Add some text to Log.i tag like Log.i("my msg", "MyFirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived"); 
Check if it's called with your app in foreground. App must be in foreground

Comment: @Debanjan it's there and it is not logged. I even debugged, and like I said. IF notification is sent from backend, it enters my breakpoint, logs. IF notification is sent by the Firebase Console, I get some type of "Default" notification and it does not enter my breakpoint/ onMessageReceived

Comment: @Debanjan IF in the app, onMessageReceived gets called, if app in foreground, it goes to the default notification which I cannot control

Comment: What you're doing, the app should receive notification when on foreground, but not when in background, cause firebase notification composer sends notification messages, but your server sends data messages.

Comment: so yes, I noticed now, if the app is open onMessageReceived is called. but if in background. I don't get onMessageReceived. I can't make to get it also there?